# Cardinality of a Banach space

Tags: banach-spaces, cardinals, dual-spaces, schauder-basis

Let $X$ be a separable infinite-dimensional Banach space.

*Assume that every element of $B_{X^{**}}$ is the weak-star limit of a sequence in $B_{X}$.*

Clearly, by the canonical embedding, we can see that $\text{card} (X) \leq \text{card}(X^{**})$.

If we choose a norm-dense sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $B_{X}$, then from our assumption, I could check that each element of $B_{X^{**}}$ is the weak-star limit of a subsequence of $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$.

Here is my question: **How can I conclude that $\text{card} (X) = \text{card}(X^{**})$ from the above observation?**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is $B_X$ etc?

Comment: @Vim Sorry, that means the unit ball (consists of vectors with norm less than or equal to 1) in the given space $X$.

Comment: What does this question have to do with Schauder bases?